# An additional letter 'S' is coming along with the price in magento

Tags: magento

I have created a store using magento. But an additional 'S' is coming along with all price.

This is the link to my site: http://store.lavatree.asia/

Any idea from where is this coming ?

Comment: Is base currency in Singapore Dollar?

Comment: The Singapore Dollar's symbol is S$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_dollar

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the issue. The base currency was Singapore Dollar.